# How to access the same label from more then one record type?

Tags: f#, label, record

Is it possible to have one function call the same label from different record types? For example lets say there are two records, defined below

```
type Pen = {
    Diameter: float
    InkColor: string
}

type Pencil = {
    Diameter: float
    Hardness: int
    Blackness: int
}
```

Can I make a function to access the Diameter label from either record type? Right now if I define a pen and pencil, the compiler is confused on which record type to use. Problem is I don't want the compiler to pick a type, of if it does pick something, allow the use of both types. The example wont compile because it expects a pencil.

```
let black_pen = {
    Diameter = 0.7
    InkColor = "Black"
}

let mechanical_pencil = {
    Diameter = 0.5
    Hardness = 1
    Blackness = 2
}

let getDiameter writing_utility = 
    let {Diameter = dia} = writing_utility
    dia

printf "%A" (getDiameter black_pen)
```

My only options I see now are:

1. Combine the records with an enumerated type to tell which is what object. Then pattern match
2. Use classes instead to use inherit
3. Use a dynamic type and reflection to check the label and type

It would be nice if I could use generics for something like this:

```
let getDiameter writing_utility = 
    let {Diameter<float> = dia} = writing_utility
    dia
```

This was as long as the record has a label "Diameter" and is a float, it will return the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should use inheritance for this, but the following works

```
let inline getDiameter (t:^q when ^q :( member Diameter:float)) = 
    (^q : (member Diameter:float) t);;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this nugget of gold.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of other options below.

Provide the mapping from "thing with diameter" to "diameter" as a function:

```
let getDiameter (util:'a) (diamFunc:'a->float) = 
    let dia = diamFunc util
    dia

getDiameter black_pen (fun x -> x.Diameter)
getDiameter mechanical_pencil (fun x -> x.Diameter)
```

Or perhaps cleaner, use DUs (great use of F# 3.1 named DU field syntax):

```
type WritingImplement =
    | Pen of diameter:float * inkColor:string
    | Pencil of float * int * int  // 3.0 syntax

let black_pen = Pen(diameter = 0.7, inkColor = "Black")
let mechanical_pencil = Pencil(0.5, 1, 2)  // 3.0 syntax

let getDiameter = function
    | Pen(diameter = d) -> d
    | Pencil(d, _, _) -> d  // 3.0 syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about what `getDiameter` do. It maps `something` to `float` i.e `'a -> float`, but it doesn't make sense because `'a` means it could be anything and mapping that anything to `float` value without knowing something about it is not gonna work. We need to make sure that we know some properties about the passed thing to get the `float` value i.e we want something like `<something with Diameter> -> float` and the best way to represent that constrain on something would be to use interface such that the signature now becomes `IWithDiameter -> float`.